# How to add height to wrapper with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, height

I need to add css height to each page dynamically with jQuery.

So far I got the following code, but it does not add height to #wrapper.

```
function getPageSizeWithScroll(){
if (window.innerHeight && window.scrollMaxY) {// Firefox
    yWithScroll = window.innerHeight + window.scrollMaxY;
    xWithScroll = window.innerWidth + window.scrollMaxX;
} else if (document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight){ // all but Explorer Mac
    yWithScroll = document.body.scrollHeight;
    xWithScroll = document.body.scrollWidth;
} else { // works in Explorer 6 Strict, Mozilla (not FF) and Safari
    yWithScroll = document.body.offsetHeight;
    xWithScroll = document.body.offsetWidth;
}
arrayPageSizeWithScroll = yWithScroll;
//alert( 'The height is ' + yWithScroll + ' and the width is ' + xWithScroll );
return arrayPageSizeWithScroll;
}
var newheight = getPageSizeWithScroll() + 30;

$('#wrapper').css({'height':'newheight'});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
$('#wrapper').css("height", newheight);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the height to the string 'newheight', instead of the value of newheight. Simply get rid of the quotes:

```
$('#wrapper').css({'height':newheight});
```

Answer (score 2):

or

```
$('#wrapper').css({height:newheight+'px');
```

Comment: or +'em' or any other if you choose not to go with pixels (of course the logic would change from the 30 value), +1 for this tidbit

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$('#wrapper').css({'height':newheight});
```

Answer (score 2):

you are assigning  a string value to your height, all you need to remove quotes and put simply a variable containing value. like

```
var newheight = getPageSizeWithScroll() + 30;

$('#wrapper').css('height':newheight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
$('#wrapper').height(newheight);
```

So many ways to do the same thing.
[height method](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height#val)